# need to change output layout in postgresql query

Tags: postgresql

I need to change the output of this query from what is in fig. 1 to the output on one line as seen in fig.2

```
select prav.id
,prav.accessionnumber
,prav.status
,prav.reviewedon as "Review Date"
,prav.reviewedby
,prav.type
,prs.score as "Score"
,prs.initiator 
,prs.addedon as "Score Date"
from workflowquality.peerreviewanalyticsview prav
left outer join workflowquality.peerreviewscore prs on prs.peerreviewid = prav.id
where prav.reviewedon > '2022-02-01 00:00:00.000-07'
```

Fig 1

[image: fig1]

Fig2

[image: fig2]

Comment: So just change the order of the fields in the field list.

Comment: where does "*Smith, Jason*" come from?

Comment: i just added that name.  The reviewer could be a different person.

Comment: As shown in desired output - when a manager is the initiator I don't want the 2nd row.  I need the manager row results to cast across columns with the matching id to the radiologist as the initiator.  So I can't just change the order of the fields.